# Tests for difference in predicted and actual trajectories in discontinuous longitudinal data

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, panel-data, change-point

I am running a longitudinal study where the dose of a drug that interferes with cognitive performance is reduced across four days according to two differenct schedules. The first is a gradual reduction schedule, with reductions of 100 mg per day: (Day 1 - 300mg; Day 2 - 200mg; Day 3 - 100mg; Day 4: 0mg). The second schedule is rapid reduction, which maintains dose for the first three days and then drops it to 0 on the last day (Day 1 - 300mg; Day 2 - 300mg; Day 3 - 300mg; Day 4: 0mg). Each day, after a sufficient absorption period participants are tested for differences in score on a cognitive test. I am hypothesising that the gradual reduction group's score will rise steadily across the four days, whereas the sudden reduction group's score will hold steady for three days then rise rapidly on the fourth. This is what seems to be happening. I have created a table of means and graph for each group across the four days (in R).

```
actGradual <- c(32, 34.07, 43.8, 51.93)
actSudden <- c(31.27, 33.07, 30.67, 39.13)
score <- c(actGradual, actSudden)
group <- rep(c("Actual Gradual", "Actual Sudden"), each = 4)
day <- rep(1:4, times = 2)
df <- data.frame(score = score, day = day, group = group)
df

ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = score)) + 
       geom_line(aes(linetype = group, color = group)) + 
       scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1)) +
       scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey")) +
       coord_cartesian(ylim = c(20,60))
```

If I treat the four time points as linear and run a linear mixed-effects model I get the following results for the fixed effects.

```
                      Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)       29.653620  3.597707 88  8.242367  0.0000
day                6.870616  1.460155 88  4.705402  0.0000
group              1.298452  5.100236 26  0.254587  0.8010
day:group         -4.720678  2.066626 88 -2.284244  0.0248
```

however a standard linear model isn't really appropriate here as the key question is 'is there a difference across the two groups in the **change in trajectory** from the third day to the fourth day *compared to the trajectory across the three previous days*?'.

Though it looks as if the actual change from the third to fourth day is the same in both the gradual and sudden groups, the sudden group's *trajectory* across days 1 to 3 changes dramatically from days 3 to 4. In contrast the gradual group's trajectory from timepoint 3 to 4 is more or less the same as it was across timepoints 1 - 3.

I am interested to find out what is the best approach to take in this case? I wondered if there was a way to do some kind of significance test to test the difference between the actual mean scores for each group at the day 4 point and the *predicted* mean at day 4 *based on the fitted linear trend for that group across the three previous days*?

I ran a linear regression on mean scores across days 1 to 3, then calculated the predicted fourth day's score for each group based on these three means and substituted it in for the fourth day's value. The graph has been amended accordingly. This essentially shows the difference between the expected score if the sudden group has stayed on 300mg on day four instead of dropping to 0 vs what actually occurred (and the same for the gradual dose reduction group).

```
actGradual <- c(32, 34.07, 43.8, 51.93)
actSudden <- c(31.27, 33.07, 30.67, 39.13)
fitGradual <- c(30.44, 36.28, 42.12, 47.96)
fitSudden <- c(32.38, 32.09, 31.8, 31.5)
score <- c(actGradual, actSudden, fitGradual, fitSudden)
group <- rep(c("Actual Gradual", "Actual Sudden", "Fitted Gradual", "Fitted Sudden"), each = 4)
day <- rep(1:4, times = 4)
df <- data.frame(score = score, day = day, group = group)

ggplot(df, aes(x = day, y = score)) + 
       geom_line(aes(linetype = group, color = group)) + 
       scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1,2,2)) +
       scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "grey", "black", "grey")) +
       coord_cartesian(ylim = c(20,60))
```

As you can see the discrepancy between predicted and actual mean is higher in the sudden group.

Is there any way to run a significance test to test this between-group difference in ***change in trajectory*** statistically?